# Hat matrix in python and r returns different results

Tags: r, regression, python

Let say we have 3 simple matrix as follows:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], columns=['X'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], columns=['y'])
w=[0.000024,0.134312,0.000024,0.000024,0.134312,0.134312,0.134312,0.134312,0.134312,0.015673]
```

and we want to calculate the diagonal of hat matrix on X. From [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/352), the formula is:

> HAT = X(X'WX)^-1X'

and here is my python code to calculate it:

```
w = np.diag(w)
w = pd.DataFrame(data=w)
xtw = np.dot(X.T,w)
xtwx = np.dot(xtw,X)
xtwxi = np.linalg.inv(xtwx)
xtwxixtw = np.dot(xtwxi,xtw)
xxtwxixtw = np.dot(X,xtwxixtw)
print np.diag(xxtwxixtw)
print np.diag(xxtwxixtw).sum()
```

and return:

```
[ 0.33333333  0.          0.33333333  0.33333333  0.          0.          0. 0.          0.          0.        ]

1
```

as the reference said ("The sum of the hii equals p, the number of parameters (regression coefficients including the intercept"))

and then I tried `r` and here is my `r` code:

```
print(lm.influence(lm(y ~ X - 1, weights = W), do.coef = FALSE)$hat)
print(sum(lm.influence(lm(y ~ X - 1, weights = W), do.coef = FALSE)$hat))
```

and return:

```
[0.3333333 0.1634870 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1634870 0.1634870 0.1634870 0.1634870 0.1634870 0.0190779] 

2
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why different results?